# How to create collection of objects Spark Dataset In Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, data-structures, apache-spark-dataset

I'm working on spark from last couple of months. Where Dataset is used as distributed collection of objects.

I'm not worrying about how its being distributed but a basic data structure. I'm curious to know how it can be placed in java If would have created my own Dataset something like that.

It looks like this `Dataset<Row>`. Where Row is record and can be many.

That's how it works to be create `Dataset<Row>`

```
List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
for (Employee e : employees) {

    rows.add(RowFactory.create(e.getFirstname(), 
                    e.getLastname(), 
                    e.getTitle(), 
                    e.getId(),
                    e.getDivision(), 
                    e.getSupervisor()));
}

return rows.iterator();
```

And above gives me like this `Dataset<Row>`

Can anyone please share how this can be placed in Java ? I mean some code in java which is responsible to to create something like this `Dataset<Row>`

I'm not asking to full fledge code, just a basic idea how it looks like so that I could clearly imagine what it looks like in backend.

Basic small sample data structure will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can create a dataset of rows from a list in several ways by [createDataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#createDataFrame-java.util.List-java.lang.Class-):

```
Dataset<Row> datasetRows = spark.createDataFrame(employeesList, Employee.class);
```

Update: If you want to know how it works under the hood then you need to take a look at Spark sources in [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala#L461), but you will be rewriting what the API is providing which simplicity and abstraction. I prefer to not manipulate Row object because it is dynamic and accept a list of values. Using your Java objects like Employee helps you to write Less Error-Prone Code and to have homogenous stored data.

Comment: I'm trying to find how to create data structure so that I could get this Dataset<Row> ? Meaning how spark.createDataFrame is working. At a basic level in Java only